# Pandas creating a new column with value from other

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, logic

hope all is fine with you, and thank you for your time and help.

My question is:

I want to create a new column in a dataframe based on:
if value on df["A"] == df ["B"] then df["new"] is the df["B"]

something like this:

```
   A     B      C
   100   100   colors
   100   10021  Blue
   100   10022  Red
.
.
.
   200   200    Shape
   200   20021  Square
   200   20022  Circle
```

what i need is a new column that while in df["A"] == df["B"] , df["new"] = colors..

```
        A     B      C    new
   100   100   colors    colors
   100   10021  Blue     colors
   100   10022  Red      colors
.
.
.
   200   200    Shape    shape
   200   20021  Square   shape
   200   20022  Circle   shape
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If same values in both columns are always first of groups is possible use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for missing values for not same values and then forward filling them by `ffill`:

```
df['new'] = df['C'].where((df["A"] == df ["B"])).ffill()
print (df)
     A      B       C     new
0  100    100  colors  colors
1  100  10021    Blue  colors
2  100  10022     Red  colors
3  200    200   Shape   Shape
4  200  20021  Square   Shape
5  200  20022  Circle   Shape
```

Comment: Thank you Jezrael. you saved me